# How to save fasttext model in binary and text formats?

Tags: gensim, fasttext

The [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html) is a bit unclear how to save the fasttext model to disk - how do you specify a path in the argument, I tried doing so and it failed with an error

Example in documentation

```
>>> from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile
>>>
>>> fname = get_tmpfile("fasttext.model")
>>>
>>> model.save(fname)
>>> model = FastText.load(fname)
```

Furthermore, how can I save the model in text format like can be done with word2vec models?

```
'word2vecmodel.wv.save_word2vec_format("D:\w2vmodel.txt")'
```

**EDIT**

After trying the suggestion to make a file first I keep kgetting the same error as before when I run this code

```
savepath = os.path.abspath('D:\fasttextmodel.v3.bin');
from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile
fname = get_tmpfile(savepath)
fasttext_model.save(fname)
```

> TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute

Answer (score 0):

Documentation in FastText `save()/load()` example is misleading, they suggest you use `get_tmpfile`. I am able to save the model if I pass the data file name as a string and do not wrap it in `get_tmpfile`:

```
model.save("fasttext.model")
```

Then you can load the same way, passing the string directly:

```
model = FastText.load("fasttext.model")
```

Note that this will save multiple files for models that are large. However, when you load the model, you only need to specify the main `fasttext.model file`, and the function will automatically load additional files, if there are any.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try creating a file in your local directory called "fasttext.model" before trying to save it?

Also, I'm assuming you trained the model before this correct?

Comment: yes I trained the model, but I didn't know you had to create a blank file first, please see my edit - after trying to create a file I get the same error as before

Comment: You don't have to create a blank file first - but trying that could reveal if you are even allowed to create files there, or if there's some other permissions problem (outside of your specific gensim/FastText choices).